# Swift 3 Programming Showing & Hidding Text

Tags: swift

Hi guys Im needing help with showing and hiding a Bit of text from a sign in and sign up its the name from the sign up I want taking away on the sign in

also I'm really new at this so please all help would be appreciated

this is my code

```
 func handleLoginRegisterChange() {
    let title = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    loginRegisterButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    // change height of ImputContainerView
    inputsContrainerViewHeightAnchor?.constant = loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 100 : 150

    // change height of nameTextField
     nameTextField.isHidden = true
     nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = false
     nameTextFieldHeightAnchor = nameTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContainerView.heightAnchor, multiplier: loginRegisterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? 0 : 1/3)
    nameTextFieldHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
    nameTextField.isHidden = false
}
```

I think that all you need

[My Coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ppP.png)

Comment: Please post code (text) rather than a screenshot.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?e3tlbb86nxrh9i2

Comment: I dunno if this is want you want but its all my code cheers